# How to open a (.log) file from my macOS app?

Tags: swift, macos

I need to open a `.log` file programmatically from my macOS app (written in SwiftUI.) I tried the following:

```
NSWorkspace.shared.launchApplication("/opt/my_log/my.log")
```

but it doesn't do anything and I get the following in the debugging console:

```
2023-03-29 19:09:20.010539+0300 MyApp [94219:6031169] [open] LAUNCH: request execute thru runningboard of 0x0-0xb93b93 (null)//opt/my_log/my.log failed with error=Error Domain=RBSRequestErrorDomain Code=5 "Launch failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Launch failed., NSUnderlyingError=0x600001d32bb0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=111 "Unknown error: 111" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Launchd job spawn failed}}}

2023-03-29 19:09:20.065015+0300 MyApp [94219:6031169] [open] LAUNCH: Launch failure with -10810/kLSUnknownErr <FSNode 0x6000013f8b40> { isDir = n, path = '/opt/my_log/my.log' }
```

If I double-click that .log file in Finder it opens it in the Console app:

[image]

But how do I open it programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the name implies `launchApplication` expects an URL representing an application.

The API which opens a **file** using a specific application is

```
let logURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/opt/my_log/my.log")
let consoleURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/System/Applications/Utilities/Console.app/")

var configuration = NSWorkspace.OpenConfiguration()
configuration.activates = true
NSWorkspace.shared.open([logURL], withApplicationAt: consoleURL, configuration: configuration)
```

Side note: If the application is sandboxed you don't have the permission to open files programmatically outside of the application container.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. And no, it's not sandboxed. I am writing a GUI app for my launch daemon. (So obviously this won't go near the Apple's Appstore. So no need to sandbox.)

Comment: Also quick follow-up. Do I need to try/catch anything in it? How does it handle errors?

Comment: The [API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/3172702-open) provides an optional completion handler (also available as `async/await` version)